# Facebook Tagged parameter for Fan Pages doens't return all posts

Tags: facebook

I have a problem that I'm trying to solve for days already. My situation is following:
1. I have a facebook app that is a simple contest.
2. The idea of the contest is for users to Tag appication page on their wall-posts (@Aldagi Auto 3.8%)
3. Application tracks how many times each user has tagged the page and creates rating
4. winner is the one who tags the most

But the problem I have is that whenever I use: https://graph.facebook.com/131494640288461/tagged
each time the result doesn't contain all the tags. 
I tried using different access tokens and the strange thing is that each access token results in different users being visible in the response.

Can anyone help me out and tell me how it is possible to get all the Posts using a specific access token?

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm also interested in this, did you find a solution?